# How to identify if a TreeTableNode in a JXTreeTable is hidden?

Tags: java, swing, swingx, treetable, jxtreetable

I'm using swingx `JXTreeTable` and would like to determine if either a leaf node (`AbstractMutableTreeTableNode`) is hidden or  a parent node is closed.

I cann't seem to find an obvious way of doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: sorry `SwingX` isn't my cup of Java isn't there implemented method `isExpanded` or `isCollapsed`???, I think required to iterating betweens visible `paths`???, maybe `paths` and `rows` too???

Comment: just the same as in a plain JTree (modulo api we might have forgotten to exposse in JXTreeTable, if you hit such a case, please file an issue in the SwingX issue tracker :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the [`isCollapsed`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-core/1.6.2/swingx-core-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html#isCollapsed%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29), [`isExpanded`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-core/1.6.2/swingx-core-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html#isExpanded%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29), [`isVisible`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/swinglabs/swingx-core/1.6.2/swingx-core-1.6.2-javadoc.jar!/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTreeTable.html#isVisible%28javax.swing.tree.TreePath%29) methods on the `JXTreeTable`. Those should be sufficient to fulfill your needs.

mKorbel already suggested this in his comments.

If this is not what you are looking for, please clarify your question